# Drop primary key programatically in magento 1

Tags: magento-1, sql

This is my code, which creates my table:

```
$table = $this->getConnection()
    ->newTable($this->getTable('namespace_reviewcache/review_store'))
    ->addColumn('review_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, [
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true
    ], 'Review ID')
    ->addColumn('store_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, [
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true
    ], 'Store ID')
    ->addIndex($this->getIdxName('namespace_reviewcache/review_store', ['store_id']), ['store_id'])
    ->addForeignKey(
        $this->getFkName('namespace_reviewcache/review_store', 'review_id', 'namespace_reviewcache/review', 'entity_id'),
        'review_id',
        $this->getTable('namespace_reviewcache/review'),
        'entity_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
    )
    ->addForeignKey(
        $this->getFkName('namespace_reviewcache/review_store', 'store_id', 'core/store', 'store_id'),
        'store_id',
        $this->getTable('core/store'),
        'store_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
    )
    ->setComment('Reviews To Store Linkage Table');
```

Im trying with an upgrade to drop the primary key store_id. This is my try:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()->dropKey(
    $this->getTable('namespace_reviewcache/review_store'),'store_id'
);
```

I get no errors and store_id is still primary after this. Any idea ? how can i fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

try using "primary", instead column name:

```
$installer->getConnection()->dropKey(
    $this->getTable('namespace_reviewcache/review_store'),
    'primary'
);
```